# Secrets for pipeline in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I have Bamboo 6.6.0 and pipelines in YAML format,

Pipeline needs some secrets: passwords, configs, and ssh keys.

Bamboo Global variables are ok for passwords, but how can I store ssh keys and config files in a secure way in Bamboo?

Answer (score 1):

The only decent way I've found so far is to encrypt ssh key with base64, put it into Bamboo Global variable (it MUST has **secret** word in name to be not visible in GUI and logs) and decrypt it during pipeline execution. 
Example:

```
---
project:
  key: LAMBDA
  plan:
    key: LAMBDA
    name: GaaS Example Lambda Scripted
stages: #TODO: Clean workspace
  - jobs:
    - dockerImage: kagarlickij/example-lambda
      scripts:
        - echo "Creating .ssh dir.." && mkdir ~/.ssh
        - echo "Exporting SSH key from Bamboo Global vars to env var.." && export BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY=${bamboo.bitbucket_ssh_key_secret}
        - echo "Decrypting SSH key.." && if [ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then rm -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ; fi && echo $BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - echo "Adding BitBucket to known_hosts.." && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: FYI for anyone who finds this later, Base64 is emphatically NOT encryption. It's easily reversed, and it should be considered the same as plain text.